# Angular 1 Offline App Model Sync with Rails Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ionic-framework, offline

I'm trying to build an Ionic 1 app (Ionic is based on AngularJS) which communicates with a Rails 5 backend via [angularjs-rails-resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource).

This app should allow us to perform CRUD operations (create, read, update, destroy) on, let's say a `Post` model. While offline, the user should be able to perform several operations, i.e.

- Delete `Post` 7 (previously fetched from the server and saved locally)
- Edit `Post` 6
- Create a new `Post`
- Edit this new `Post`

This implies, that our newly created `Post` is listed in our list of `Posts` even if this change is not yet sent to the server.

Later on, when the connection is reestablished, those changes should be sent to the Rails backend in a synchronous way (we cannot edit a `Post` which has not yet been created).

I could not find a tool matching my criteria:

PouchDB requires a CouchDB server, but that's not an option here, and setting up PouchDB, CouchDB and a RailsDB <-> CouchDB autosync functionality seems like overkill.

My first idea is to add some interceptors to [angularjs-rails-resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource), which roughly do this:

- After any online request: Save the result locally
- After offline `GET` request: Return the locally saved data
- After offline `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` request: Queue this request for future retry and perform this action (i.e. `POST`) on the local data

Is this a good way to do this? This problem seems to me like many app developers should have it, but I couldn't find a nice solution for it by now, which makes me wonder if I missed something.

Comment: did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: I'm not using Ionic anymore because of the poor performance. Now I'm using React Native with Realm (an offline database) and I'm going to implement the logic as I proposed.

Comment: How bad was Ionic? Usable for small apps, or basically just not worth the effort?

Comment: Testing various existing Ionic 1 apps (don't know about Ionic 2), I realized that the performance is mostly bad. It is possible to make a good small Ionic 1 app with good performance, but you are always bound to the performance limits of the in-app-browser (as you are still with Ionic 2).